# Filling Cascading dropdown from database during edit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, cascadingdropdown

I need help filling dependent dropdowns. I have dependent dropdown that work when entering data, select the State dropdown and the dependent dropdowns reload based on the state selected.

Issue is when I want to edit, the state is filled and selected from database, but the dependents don't get filled and selected. The `onChange` function doesn't get activated or hit.

Here are my codes:

```
<div class="form-row">

                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="Sposted"></label>
                                        <select asp-for="Sposted"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.statelist, "Stateid", "Statename" ))"
                                                onchange="sposted(this)">
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="Pcommand"></label>
                                        <select asp-for="Pcommand" class="form-control" id="Pcommand"
                                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "Commandid", "Cfname"))">
                                            <option>Select ...</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="PayP"></label>
                                        <select asp-for="PayP" id="PayP"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "Ppid", "Ppfull"))"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

The 2 dropdowns, `Pcommand` and `PayP` are dependent on `sposted`. Again, when editing, the `sposted` drop down is selected and filled from db, but doesn't cascade to the other 2.

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            //$(document).ready(function () {
                //$('#Sposted').change(function () {
                function sposted(stateid) {
                    console.log(stateid.value);
                    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "MemberList/RetPayPoint";
                    //var ddlsource = "#Sposted";
                    //$.getJSON(url, { Stateid: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    $.getJSON(url, { Stateid: stateid.value }, function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $("#PayP").empty();
                        $.each(data, function (i, pp) {
                            items += "<option value='" + pp.value + "'>" + pp.text + "</option>";
                        });
                        $('#PayP').html(items);
                    });
                }//});
          //  });

    </script>
```

Thank you in advance.

A few days later, I have decided to add the controller method that is supposed to fill the dropdowns in the view.

```
public IActionResult DisplayMem()
        {
            var statelist = _mr.GetStates().ToList();
            statelist.Insert(0, new ToxState { Stateid = 0, Statename = "Select..." });
            ViewBag.statelist = statelist;

            var rank = _mr.GetRanks().ToList();
            rank.Insert(0, new ToxRank { Rankid = 0, Fullname = "Select..." });
            ViewBag.rank = rank;
            //memid = memlist.FirstOrDefault().MemberId;
            var obj = _mr.MemberInfo((long)_ar.FindAcc(long.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("memberid"))).MemId);
            return View(obj);
        }
```

All he information needed to fill the view elements are in obj. It loads the selects the state from the id in obj, but the onchange isn't fired to fill the dependent dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of research, I couldn't seem to find a way to to force the `onchange` to call Ajax to dynamically fill the dependent dropdowns. So I took a cue from Mateen's 3rd comment and rewrote the method in the controller to read load the relevant items into a ViewBag.

```
public IActionResult DisplayMem()
        {
            var statelist = _mr.GetStates().ToList();
            statelist.Insert(0, new ToxState { Stateid = 0, Statename = "Select..." });
            ViewBag.statelist = statelist;

            var rank = _mr.GetRanks().ToList();
            rank.Insert(0, new ToxRank { Rankid = 0, Fullname = "Select..." });
            ViewBag.rank = rank;
            var obj = _mr.MemberInfo((long)_ar.FindAcc(long.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("memberid"))).MemId);

            
            ViewBag.payp = _mr.GetPayPoint(obj.Sposted.Value).ToList();
            ViewBag.pcommand = _mr.GetCommand(obj.Sposted.Value).ToList();


            return View(obj);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When editing using selected `stateid` you need to get both dropdowns data, just like you are getting `PayP` data by using selected `stateid` like:

```
  $.getJSON(url, { Stateid: stateid.value }, function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#PayP").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, pp) {
                        items += "<option value='" + pp.value + "'>" + pp.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#PayP').html(items);
                });
```

You will call your function `sposted` and pass selected `stateid` both times while creating or editing.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. In the controller, I have read all the values needed into an object and pass the view, it's from the object that the stateid is selected from the loaded drop-down values.

Comment: Great! glad to know this one helped you, if you find this answer useful please mark this as a correct answer, Thanks

Comment: I have not yet solved the issue, I only pointed out that I already have the contents of the record from db in an object that is passed.

Comment: Ok if you get the data then pass it to the view dropdown just like you passed in `asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.statelist, ..` pass your viewBag in other dropdowns also you are passing empty list `asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty,`

Comment: Yes I know. Issue is the contents of the dependent  dropdown needs to be filled before the selected value can be selected. When the state dropdown is selected, ajax is supposed to fill the contents of the dependents before the selected value can be assigned to it. I hope I was able to explain better.